# Splitting of string and how to join afterward lines?

Tags: c#

I have a text file in which address are written in a manner
i.e.

```
>
8,SENT VILA,
BESIDE GREEN RESIDANSY,MJ
>
10/787, BRUNSITK
PEL ROAD,
SEM TIC 7840
>
2/4596,
MAIN ROAD,
10/787, PAL
PEL ROAD,
SEM TIC 7840
```

when I split string with '>', it gives all result in an arry.

Here is my code..

```
var x = File.ReadAllText(text file path);
var y = x.Split(x,StringSplitOptions.None);
var z = string.Join("", y.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(z);
```

What I want to do is split with '>' and Join the lines with space as a separator below.

i.e.

- 8,SENT VILA,BESIDE GREEN RESIDANSY,MJ
- 10/787, BRUNSITK PEL ROAD, SEM TIC 7840

Any ideas? I tried searching plenty of questions, but is not like this one.

Comment: `x.Split(x,StringSplitOptions.None);`  ?  you split x by itself?

Comment: split x by ">" then you got a list of strings. For each string, split it at "\n"  and join with " " .

Comment: `string.Join("", y.ToArray());` -> doesn't make sense. `y` is already an array, no need for that `ToArray()`; `""` joins with no space when your question claims you want to join the lines with a space

Comment: So you want `x = x.Replace('>', ' ');`?

Comment: I would also add `var x = File.ReadAllText(text file path).Replace("\r\n", "");` so that newlines are removed.

Comment: First of all, how do you plan to use this later? I'm asking because it seems unsafe to use space as a splitter here if you want to be able to split the addresses again later. How do you know that `MJ` and `10/787` belong to two different addresses, but that `SENT` and `VILA` belong to the same one? Why not use e.g. `;` or `|`, or something else to split instead?

Comment: Just don't use Split().  Google "c# parse csv" to find solutions to this very common need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I think you should read the file as an array:</strike>

```
var a = File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

Then you can drop the '>' by LINQ "where line not startswith >" when you join with space:

```
var r = string.Join(" ", a.Where(line => !line.StartsWith(">")))
```

There is some inconsistency in your input, your desire and your example output; for example the address with `PAL` seems to have disappeared from the expected output, and you didn't put a space between `VILA,` and `BESIDE` but did put one between `BRUNSITK` and `PEL` and also between `ROAD,` and `SEM`.

I don't really know how to rationalize these, but I'm sure you can  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

---

Edit, in response to question edit..

OK, so how about reading the file, splitting on > then removing the line breaks:

```
var addresses = File.ReadAllText(path)
  .Split('>')
  .Select(e => e.Replace("\r\n"," "))
```

If the file lines are terminated by just \n, adjust the replacement..

If you just want a single string out maybe the simplest thing is a double replacement :

```
var s = File.ReadAllText(path).Replace("\r\n"," ").Replace(">", "\r\n")
```

i.e. remove ALL the line breaks and then change the > to line breaks..

Comment: Hi Caius, I have to gather all address in one line separately regardless of special characters.

Comment: Thanks @Caius for the great answer. Its good that Linq can do such things. I am new at that.

Comment: LINQ could also do, I suppose: `string.Concat(File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(line => line == ">" ? "\r\n" : line))` (if you wanted a single string with many lines, one address per line) :D